# Consecutive, distinct sequences in C++ 11 using Atomic

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I have two questions about atomics:

1) Is the following code guaranteed to return consecutive, monotonically increasing sequences without duplicates in a multi-threaded setup?

```
#include <atomic>

struct AtomicCounter {
    std::atomic<int> value;

    AtomicCounter() : value( 0 ) {}

    int getNextSequence(){
    return ++value;
    }
};
```

2) Is there a simpler way to initialize? None of these worked:

```
std::atomic<int> value ( 0 ) ;
std::atomic<int> value { 0 } ;
std::atomic<int> value=0;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

1. Yes, you will get a sequence without gaps or duplicates, even in concurrent environments. The "monotonically increasing" implies sequencing on the part of the caller - in the sense that to define what comes before and what comes after you need to define in what sequence the events take place. For example, there is no guarantee that the thread that initiates the call first among several concurrent threads would necessarily get a smaller value.
2. The `atomic<int> value {0};` is the right syntax ([demo](http://ideone.com/sszUnp)). However, not all C++ compilers provide support for non-static data member initializers of C++11, so using the initializer list of C++98 may be the only way available to you at the moment.

Here is a [link to C++11 feature lists](http://cpprocks.com/c11-compiler-support-shootout-visual-studio-gcc-clang-intel/) implemented by various compilers.

Comment: Well `atomic` is c++11 too it would be strange if one feature worked and the other not, but it is the right syntax.

Comment: @luk32 That wouldn't be a single bit strange: the level of support of C++11 [differs a lot compiler to compiler](http://cpprocks.com/c11-compiler-support-shootout-visual-studio-gcc-clang-intel/). Specifically, MSVC supports atomic, but it does not support non-static data member initializers.

Comment: You should mention `monotonically increasing` is definitely not guaranteed, unless the operations are sequenced externally, as "before" is not well defined without that.  :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it is.
2. You can't initialize like that inside a class body, you need to use the initializer list syntax you're currently using.

Comment: 2. Yes, you can since c++11. Is right syntax `atomic<int> value {0};`.